# Export Processmaker Collection Records to Excel - Processmaker

Tags: processmaker

Please, how can I export collection records to a downloadable excel? I have written a script that collects the records and put them in an array but I need a way to put the array records in an excel sheet that can be downloaded by users.

Comment: Which language are you using to write the script? Javascrript, PHP ...? If it is PHP I believe there are libraries to work with spreadsheets ... for example https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: @osantos PHP. I finally found a way around it. Thanks.

Comment: it would be nice if you could explain how you did it by answering your own question . I would be interested in knowing